# How to cancel Work from WorkManager in Android?

Tags: android, realm, android-workmanager

I have saved the WorkManager `UUID` converted to `String` in Realm database.

Here is the code -

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();
            Data inputData = new Data.Builder().putString("downloadUrl", downloadUrl).
                    putString("destinationFolder", destinationFolder).
                    putInt("suraNumber", Integer.parseInt(suraNumber)).
                    putString("fileName", fileName).
                    putBoolean("downloadFileTypeBangla", downloadFileTypeBangla).
                    putBoolean("downloadFileTypeArabic", downloadFileTypeArabic).
                    putBoolean("downloadFileTypeArabicWithBangla", downloadFileTypeArabicWithBangla).build();
            OneTimeWorkRequest downloadWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DownloadWorker.class).setConstraints(constraints).setInputData(inputData).build();
            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(downloadWork);

            Sura sura = dbOperations.getSuraById(Integer.parseInt(suraNumber));
            if(sura != null){
                dbOperations.updateSura(sura, Integer.parseInt(suraNumber), sura.getBnAudioDownloadStatus(), sura.getArAudioDownloadStatus(), 1);
                realm.beginTransaction();
                DownloadStatusModel downloadStatusModel = new DownloadStatusModel();
                downloadStatusModel.setId(new RealmCommonService(realm).newId(DownloadStatusModel.class));
                downloadStatusModel.setDownloadFileType("ArabicWithBangla");
                downloadStatusModel.setActiveStatus(true);
                downloadStatusModel.setDownloadDate(new Date());
                downloadStatusModel.setDownloadedSuraNo(sura.getSuraNo());
                downloadStatusModel.setDownloadFileSize(sura.getArBnAudioFileSize());
                downloadStatusModel.setDownloadReferenceId(downloadWork.getId().toString());
                downloadStatusModel.setDownloadedSuraNameBangla(sura.getSuraNameBangla());
                downloadStatusModel.setDownloadStatus(1);
                realm.copyToRealm(downloadStatusModel);
                realm.commitTransaction();
            }
```

**Now I'm trying to cancel the `Work` using this line of code but didn't work.**

```
WorkManager.getInstance().cancelWorkById(UUID.fromString(downloadStatusModel.getDownloadReferenceId()));
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

**Thanks**

Comment: Try cancelling work by tag `cancelAllWorkByTag` and provide same tag to your worker. But remember that it works if your work is unfinished.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 

Will it cancel my all works that I have enqueued?

Comment: Yes !, it would. May be your issue is not with **UUID** but it's already finished *(Just guessing)*.

Comment: No luck. cancelAllWorkByTag  not working. My work is not finished also. I have debugged that.

Comment: What do you mean 'it didn't work'? How are you checking that it wasn't cancelled? Does your `Worker` get a callback to `onStopped()`?

Comment: I mean it wasn't canceled. I am downloading a file in the working class after cancelling the work it continues downloading.  

   I didn't test by implementing the onStopped method. Let me try this. 

Thanks @ianhanniballake

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake it worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using `Worker`, you need to override the [`onStopped()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.html#onStopped()) method and use that as the signal for your worker to cancel its ongoing work. Within your `doWork()` method, you can also use [`isStopped()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#isStopped()) to check for cancellation.

Comment: `onStopped()` is final in `CoroutineWorker`, and the docs mention to use the `afterDone()` method on the future along with an `isCancelled` check, however in my use case, I have it as a foreground long running worker and am cancelling with a CancellingPendingIntent. How can I cleanup within the worker itself?

Comment: @CyberShark - as per [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker), your suspending `doWork` gets cancelled, so you'd want to handle it like cancellation of any other suspending method e.g. a try/finally block that would ensure the finally block is run whether you are cancelled or not.

Comment: `cancelUniqueWork` doesn't work for my `CoroutineWorker`, it still executes all the code lines which are called from `doWork` func

Comment: @user924 - it absolutely does, just keep in mind that [coroutine cancellation is cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative). If you aren't using suspending method (which provide an automatic cancellation point) or checking `isActive`, then you aren't handling cancellation properly in your code. That has nothing to do with `cancelUniqueWork` not working as it should.

Comment: @ianhanniballake what do you mean by `"aren't using suspending method`? there is `suspend fun doWork()` in `CoroutineWorker`... after `cancelUniqueWork` the func `isStopped()` still returns false after checking it several times while the code is executed

Comment: @user924 - did you read the page I linked? It has a [whole section on making code cancellable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#making-computation-code-cancellable), which, as I pointed out, involves either invoking a suspending method or using `isActive`. That's what you should be doing inside your `doWork` method, not checking `isStopped` (which is not going to be thread safe, unlike `isActive`).

Comment: @ianhanniballake `doWork` is already suspending function, ok, so just need to use `isActive` instead of `isStopped`...

Comment: What if inside the Worker I want to signal that I want to cancel it, using "stop()" function? It has some various flags, but none seem to match manual stopping from within ...