# WorkManager how to interrupt process

Tags: android

i have a list of object to send to backend with api, is there a way to interrupt the process. `workManager.cancelAll` or bytag or by id don't work because the state is RUNNING. Any suggestions?

```
class UploadWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters)
    : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

lateinit var DBHelper: DatabaseHelper
val CHANNEL_ID = "UploadOfflinePhoto"
lateinit var offlinePhotoList: MutableList<OfflinePhoto>

lateinit var error: Error
lateinit var resultInfo: Result_Info
lateinit var imageData: Image_Data


var photoCertificatedTail: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
var photoNotCertificatedTail: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
lateinit var offlinePhotoListToDeleteFlag: MutableList<OfflinePhoto>
var count: Int = 0

companion object {
    private const val WORK_NAME = "UploadOfflinePhoto"
    var workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
    fun stop(){
        Log.e("WorkInfo", "CANCELL ALL")
        //workManager.cancelAllWork()
    }

}




override fun doWork(): Result {
    // Do the work here--in this case, upload the images.

    DBHelper = DatabaseHelper(applicationContext)
    offlinePhotoList = DBHelper.offlinePhoto

    Log.e("WORK-MANAGER", "${offlinePhotoList.size}")
    if(offlinePhotoList.size > 0){
        uploadOfflineTail(offlinePhotoList[count])
    }




    val output = Data.Builder()
            .putIntArray("photoCertificatedTail",photoCertificatedTail.toIntArray() )
            .putIntArray("photoNotCertificatedTail",photoNotCertificatedTail.toIntArray() )
            .build()


    return Result.success(output)

}
```

Comment: Did you try this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441122/how-to-cancel-work-from-workmanager-in-android#answer-53443103

Comment: i tried it, but it doesn't stop the esecution